# Is it possible to use global variable that change continuously over time from matlab workspace to use with simulink?

Tags: matlab, serial-port, real-time, simulink

I've been coding a matlab program to read data from esp32 with matlab serial port connection and I extracted angular(degree or rad) and angular velocity(degree/s or rad/s) data and store them as variables name "th" and "vth" respectively, let me explain more about data I've recieved from esp32 this is the result template from reading serial data [Result data in command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cVg6.png) ["E1, t, thx , th_y , th_z, vth_x, vth_y, vth_z \n"] as you can see I have to use readline function to read string at each line and display it then read it over again and again with this function

```
configureCallback(device, "terminator", @readSerialData)
```

but I want t, th and vth values to store in my workspace so I declare global variable t, th and vth then due to configureCallback function my data have been changing continuously without changing its size (it replaced itself). You can see my code below.

```
clc
clear
close
global splitdata t th vth
portavailable = serialportlist("available");

device = serialport("COM8",500000);

%data = read(device,47,"string")
%splitdata = splitlines(data)


configureCallback(device,"terminator", @readSerialData)


function readSerialData(src,~)
    global splitdata t th vth
    alinedata = readline(src);
    disp(alinedata);

    data = evalc('disp(alinedata)'); 
    splitdata = split(data,',');
    %disp(splitdata)

    t = str2double(splitdata{2})/1000;

    th(1) = str2double(splitdata{3});
    th(2) = str2double(splitdata{4});
    th(3) = str2double(splitdata{5});

    vth(1) = str2double(splitdata{6});
    vth(2) = str2double(splitdata{7});
    vth(3) = str2double(splitdata{8});
end
```

Then I try to take these variables(t, th, vth) to use it in simulink so I just test it with "from workspace" block in Simulink library(I don't know if this is the only way to use data from workspace but if you know a better way to do please suggest me) but when I run(simulate model) the simulation in matlab(not in simulink) appear to be stop and it make my time values and th values to be constant or not update from configureCallback function as you can see in this image [Simulating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDFJA.png). data in workspace is changing overtime after I press run button in matlab but when I press run in simulink the simulation in matlab appear to be stopped so my question is "Is it possible to do this? if not what should I do?"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the serial read functions inside simulink rather than using MATLAB to receive the data and then pass it to simulink via a global variable?

Comment: I think the from workspace blocks are only evaluated once when the model runs rather than each model step (I can't find a reference for that though)